# Passthrough input to output in AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

How can I passthrough the input to a `Task` state in an AWS Step Functions to the output?

After reading the [Input and Output Processing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-input-output-processing.html) page in the AWS docs, I have played with various combinations of `InputPath`, `ResultPath` and `OutputPath`.

State definition:

```
"First State": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "[My Lambda ARN]",
    "Next": "Second State",
    "InputPath": "$.someKey",
    "OutputPath": "$"
}
```

Input:

```
{
    "someKey": "someValue"
}
```

**Expected Result**

I would like the output of the `First State` (and thus the input of `Second State`) to be

```
{
    "someKey": "someValue"
}
```

**Actual Result**

```
[empty]
```

---

What if the input is more complicated, e.g.

```
{
    "firstKey": "firstValue",
    "secondKey": "secondValue"
}
```

I would like to forward all of it without worrying about (sub) paths.

Comment: Hello, @matsev. Can you please answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345667/aws-step-functions-pass-input-to-another-task)? It is similar to what you asked. Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the [Amazon States Language](https://states-language.net/spec.html#filters) spec it is stated that:

> If the value of ResultPath is null, that means that the state’s own raw output is discarded and its raw input becomes its result.

Consequently, I updated my state definition to

```
"First State": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "[My Lambda ARN]",
    "Next": "Second State",
    "ResultPath": null
}
```

As a result, when passing the input example `Task` input payload will be copied to the output, even for rich objects like:

```
{
    "firstKey": "firstValue",
    "secondKey": "secondValue"
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For those who find themselves here using CDK, the solution is to use the explicit `aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.DISCARD` enum rather than None/null.

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_stepfunctions,
    aws_stepfunctions_tasks,
)

aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke(
    self,
    "my_function",
    lambda_function=lambda_function,
    result_path=aws_stepfunctions.JsonPath.DISCARD,
)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-stepfunctions.JsonPath.html#static-discard

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't want to just pass input to output but to add result of `Task` to input and forward all of it as output you can use `"ResultPath": "$.addedOutput"` as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for a solution from passing input from one parallel state to another parallel state and the above option worked really good.
For example my step function is like this...tas1->parallel task2 -> parallel trask3 -> task4.  So when it start with parallel task3, the input values are wiped out, so ptask3 is failing. With the above option, i was able to pass in same input from ptask2 to ptas3.

Comment: Hi spatel, this isn't an answer in it's own right, more of a comment on the answer you are referring to. Please delete this Answer and post as a comment on the matsev answer